# Doxygen struct documentation

Tags: c, struct, latex, doxygen, unions

```
    /**
    * \brief my foo struct.
    *
    * Blah blah...
    */
    typedef struct{
      uint8 a;/**< A uint8 val */
      union{
        uint32 Data;/**< A uint32 val */
        uint8 ba[4];/**< A uint8 array */
      }union1;/**< my union 1 */
      union{
        uint32 Data;/**< Another uint32 val */
        uint8 ba[4];/**< Another uint8 array */
      }union2;/**< my union 2 */
    }FooStruct;
```

I want document my struct like this. But doxygen cant generate documentation same field names like union1.Data - union2.Data. It generates document like following..

```
FooStruct::Data [1/2]
FooStruct::Data [2/2]
```

how can I document my struct prefixed by parent field names.

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using?

Comment: 1.9.1 but i think my problem not caused about version. I search flags and groping but i cant find anything

Comment: Try to give a name to each union, instead of using anonymous unions. For example `union Union1 {uint32 Data; uint8 ba[4]; } union1; union Union2 {uint32 Data; unit8 ba[4]} union2;`